# Exhausting the measure of a compact set by cover of compact intervals

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

> Let $F$ be a compact set on $\mathbb R$. Given $\epsilon>0$, write $F_\epsilon = \bigcup_{x\in F} [x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon].$ Prove that $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow \infty} m(F_\epsilon) = m(F)$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Since $F\subseteq F_\epsilon$, we have $m(F)\leq m(F_\epsilon)\leq m(F)+m(F_\epsilon\setminus F)$, so it suffices to prove that $m(F_\epsilon\setminus F)\rightarrow 0$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. The fact that $F$ is compact must be used somehow here. If we defined $F_\epsilon'= \bigcup_{x\in F}(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$, this is an open cover for $F$ such that $F\subseteq F_\epsilon'\subseteq F_\epsilon$. By compactness, we can find $x_1,\cdots,x_{\ell(\epsilon)}\in F$ such that $$F\subseteq \bigcup_{1\leq j \leq \ell(\epsilon)} (x_j-\epsilon, x_j+\epsilon).$$
Call the above finite cover by $F_\epsilon''$. Then, $F_\epsilon\setminus F = (F_\epsilon\setminus F_\epsilon'')\cup (F_\epsilon''\setminus F)$ and we have $m(F_\epsilon\setminus F) \leq m(F_\epsilon\setminus F_\epsilon'')+m(F_\epsilon''\setminus F).$ Now, how to proceed from here? How can I estimate the measures $m(F_\epsilon\setminus F_\epsilon'')$ and $m(F_\epsilon''\setminus F)?$ I am stuck here. The finite subcover depends on $\epsilon$, so that seems to make this estimation more complicated...

How to proceed from here? Is there any other better path? Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Prove that $F = \bigcap_{\varepsilon > 0} F_\varepsilon$ and then use the monotonicity properties of measures

Comment: @vizietto We can choose a decreasing sequence of $\epsilon$, so $F_{\epsilon_n}$ is decreasing. Hence, $m(F) = \lim m(F_{\epsilon_n})$. Now, to show that $\cap_n F_{\epsilon_n}\subseteq F$, we suppose $x\not\in F$. Then, $d(x,F)>0$. Choose $\epsilon_n<d(x,F)$. One cannot have $x\in [f-\epsilon_n,f+\epsilon_n]$ for some $f\in F$, because $d(x,f)<d(x,F)$. Is this correct?